# Socket hang-up using neo4j JS driver

Tags: node.js, express, neo4j

all. I'm new to neo4j and trying to use the official JS driver from node / express to hit a remote (e.g. non-local) server, but keep getting [Error: socket hang up] code: 'ECONNRESET' errors. Code looks like this:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var driver  = neo4j.driver("bolt://ip.address", neo4j.auth.basic("neo4j", "neo4j"));
  var session = driver.session();
  var query   = "MATCH (p:Person {name:'Sally'})-[r:KNOWS]->(f:Person) RETURN f";

  session
    .run(query)
    .then(function(result) {
      result.records.forEach(function(record) {
        console.log(record._fields);
      });
      session.close();
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });

  driver.close();
});
```

I've tried both the streaming and promise techniques on both bolt and http, all with the same outcome. Remote server is config'ed to accept external connections and I've verified connectivity separately via golang.

Ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks to Oscar Hane for answering this over on Github:

> Your issue is that you're potentially closing the driver before your
>   query are finished.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var driver  = neo4j.driver("bolt://ip.address", neo4j.auth.basic("neo4j", "neo4j"));
  var session = driver.session();
  var query   = "MATCH (p:Person {name:'Sally'})-[r:KNOWS]->(f:Person) RETURN f";

  session
    .run(query)
    .then(function(result) {
      result.records.forEach(function(record) {
        console.log(record._fields);
      });
      session.close();
      driver.close();
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
      driver.close();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The guide on github is so minimal, they explicit say you need to close the driver, so that was the first to place in the bottom of a test-script.